# CSS extra horizontal space

Tags: html, css, space, extra

I have been trying to removing the extra horizontal space coming in my HTML/CSS Page.

Any idea why this occurs.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the code, and point out the exact problem, we have no idea what you are specifically talking about.

Comment: Hi Hill, Sorry the source code looks like mess, code coming from master and content pages.

So i'm unable to post the code.

My Question belongs generally, How can i remove only Horizontal Scroll bar for html page?

Comment: All browsers or just a specific one?

Answer (score 2):

add a css property: (replace "html" by whatever element you want)

```
html {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

if you want to be more specific (not sure if it works anywhere but in firefox):

```
html  {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```